# creating a crystal report from a datatable that is filled from a webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to create a crystal report, however I cannot connect directly to the database. I am required to get all data from a webservice call. I am returning DataTables for each webservice call. Is there any way for me to bind that datatable to the .xsd file for the Crystal Report or is there a better way to get this information into the crystal report.

```
        protected void GenReport_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ReportDocument TestReport = new ReportDocument();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = webservice.Get_Admin_Dealers();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        dt.TableName = "TestReport";
        TestReport.Load(Server.MapPath("/TestReport.rpt"));
        TestReport.SetDataSource(ds);           
        ReportViewer.ReportSource = TestReport;

    }
```

the front side looks like

```
asp:Panel ID="reportPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="GenReport" runat="server" Text="Generate Report" OnClick="GenReport_Clicked" />
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true"></CR:CrystalReportViewer>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Hello, why don't you use SSRS, it is more efficient to do reporting , easier to use and more efficient.Have you visual studio  2008? I say that because you try to do same as SSRS http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssrs_2008_tutorial.htm

Comment: I have a client who is already using Crystal Reports and wants to be able to use crystal here as well.

Comment: can you use sql server express? because it is free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this url: [Create a crystal report form arraylist or datatable](http://forums.asp.net/t/1490795.aspx/1) .

Comment: This document was a great insight, but for some reason I keep getting the pop up requesting me to put in my credentials for a server even though I am not hitting a server. I am pulling a datatable from a webservice call and then creating the dataset and adding the datatable to the dataset, I will post the code in original question.